# How to get absolute path of image in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need to get absolute path of image in service. For example
`/var/www/shop/public/media/a6/a0/27/1681870318/b86e01f8caac46fec00a3db724c00c79.jpg`.
I have entity of MediaRepository, but it only provides `getUrl();` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to use the filesystem abstraction so you don't have to deal with full paths and stay within the constraints of the abstraction.

You inject `shopware.filesystem.public` and `UrlGeneratorInterface` to build a relative path and use the relative path for filesystem operations using the abstraction.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Content\Media\File\PathFinder">
    <!-- ... -->
    <argument type="service" id="shopware.filesystem.public"/>
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Pathname\UrlGeneratorInterface"/>
</service>
```

```php
$media = $this->mediaRepository->search(new Criteria([$mediaId]), $context)->get($mediaId);
$path = $this->urlGenerator->getRelativeMediaUrl($media);
// read, copy, delete, save the file using the filesystem abstraction
$this->publicFilesystem->read($path);
```

If you absolutely must, you can read the file as a stream and retrieve the absolute path from the `resource` object.

```php
$stream = $this->publicFilesystem->readStream($path);
$metaData = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
$absolutePath = $metaData['uri'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an image on custom frontend page you can simply display it by
pasting belowcode in your .twig file:

```
{% set sportsMediaId = product.image %}
{% set mediaCollection = searchMedia([sportsMediaId], context.context) %}
{% set sportsMedia = mediaCollection.get(sportsMediaId) %}
<img src="{{sportsMedia.url}}" width="700" height="500">
```

With the "product.image" being the media id of image coming from database.