# Shopware 6 Cloning Media via PHP

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need to make backup of certain Media Files.

They are provided as array. Code make new UUID, copy properties and saves to database. This is working. The problem is I can't upload file to that database entry. I've got error:
`Object { status: "500", code: "CONTENT__MEDIA_DUPLICATED_FILE_NAME", title: "Internal Server Error"...`

```php
    function makeBackup(array $images, Context $context) :bool
    {
        foreach ($images as $i) {
            $uuid = Uuid::randomHex();
            $path = $this->urlGeneratorInterface->getRelativeMediaUrl($i);
            try {
                $this->publicFileSystem->read($path);
                $stream = $this->publicFileSystem->readStream($path);
                $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
                $oldFileNameWithPath = $metaData['uri'];
            }catch (UnableToReadFile $e){
                echo "[ERROR] File $path does not exists. Continuing.\n";
                continue;
            }

            $mimeType = mime_content_type($oldFileNameWithPath);
            $fileExtension = pathinfo($oldFileNameWithPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fileSize = filesize($oldFileNameWithPath);
            $fileName = pathinfo($oldFileNameWithPath, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '_old.' . $fileExtension;
            $mediaFile = new MediaFile($fileName, $mimeType, $fileExtension, $fileSize);

            $backupMediaData = [
                'id' => $uuid,
                'fileName' => $i->getFileName()."_old",
                'mimeType' => $i->getMimeType(),
                'fileSize' => $i->getFileSize(),
                // 'mediaFolderId' => $media->getMediaFolderId(),
                'createdAt' => $i->getCreatedAt(),
                'updatedAt' => $i->getUpdatedAt(),
                'alt' => $i->getAlt(),
                'title' => $i->getTitle()."_old",
            ];
            $this->mediaRepository->create([$backupMediaData], $context);

           $this->fileSaver->persistFileToMedia(
                $mediaFile,
                pathinfo($oldFileNameWithPath, PATHINFO_FILENAME),
                $uuid,
                $context
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I changed filename name, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the original media related services, you'll find that the `media` entity is initially persisted without the `fileName` and other meta data info about the file. The `persistFileToMedia` method then checks whether a media entity with the file name you're trying to upload already exists. Since you're persisting one with that exact name just prior, you'll run into that exception.

To make life a little bit easier, you can also use the `clone` method of the repository, to create a copy. You can define a behavior for the clone, where you can override certain properties. Finally you'll have to execute the clone command within a system-scoped context, as normally you wouldn't be allowed to directly write the `fileName` property, since that would normally be the job of the file saver abstraction, e.g. that method `persistFileToMedia` you're calling.

Example:

```php
// to write fileName and other metadata directly, you need the system scope
$newMediaId = $context->scope(Context::SYSTEM_SCOPE, function (Context $context) use ($oldMediaId): string {
    $behavior = new CloneBehavior([
        'mimeType' => null,
        'fileExtension' => null,
        'uploadedAt' => null,
        'fileName' => null,
        'fileSize' => null,
        'metaData' => null,
    ]);

    $newMediaId = Uuid::randomHex();
    $this->mediaRepository->clone($oldMediaId, $context, $newMediaId, $behavior);

    return $newMediaId;
});

$this->fileSaver->persistFileToMedia(
    $mediaFile,
    $originalFileName . '_old',
    $newMediaId,
    $context
);
```

Comment: `Warning: getimagesize(schokolade_600x600_old.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` in `persistFileToMedia` I still don't get it. What are diff between MediaFile and Destination parameter in persistFileToMedia https://pastebin.com/eujMvr01

Comment: It needs to be absolute path to the file, not just the file name and extension. See this answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76200992/8556259

Comment: I get `CONTENT__MEDIA_ILLEGAL_FILE_NAME","title":"Internal Server Error","detail":"Provided filename \u0022media\/d7\/94\/37\/1689687877\/schokolade_600x600.jpg\u0022 is not permitted: ` in persistFileToMedia second arg if i use `$this->urlGeneratorInterface->getRelativeMediaUrl($i);` there

Comment: That's still not the absolute path. As the name suggests, that's the relative path beginning within the `public` direct. You need to prepend the rest of the path up to the `public` directory.

Comment: `'Provided filename "/var/www/html/public/media/8d/c5/83/1689687877/shirt_red_600x600.jpg" is not permitted: Filename must not contain "/"'` in `persistFileToMedia` second argument. I still don't get it.

Comment: The `MediaFile` needs the absolute path, the second argument of `persistFileToMedia` is just the file name.